# Writing Logs from Console Shell

Tags: shell, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I have been using CakePHP 2.4.4 to build the interactive web part of my app and that is going very well.  CakePHP is awesome.

I am now doing some supporting background processes.  The Console and Shell seems to be the way to do it as it has access to the Models.

I have written the code and have it working but I am trying to write to the same log that I use for the Models.  In the models I have an afterSave function to log all the database changes and I just used the `$this->log("$model $logEntry", 'info');` to write to the log.

That doesn't work in the Shell but I thought the `CakeLog::write('info', "$model $logEntry");` might work but it doesn't either.

Do I need to initialise the CakeLog to point to the correct log files?

```
<?php
App::uses('CakeTime', 'Utility');
App::uses('CakeLog', 'Utility');

class ProcessRequestShell extends AppShell {
    //Need to access the request and monitor tables
    public $uses = array('Request');

    private function updateRequest($data){
        $model = 'Request';
        $result = $this->Request->save($data);

        $logEntry = "UPDATE ProcessRequestShell ";
        foreach ($data[$model] AS $k => $v){$logEntry .= "$k='$v' ";}
        if ($result){
            //$this->log("$model $logEntry", 'info');
            CakeLog::write('info', "$model $logEntry");
        } else {
            //$this->log("$model FAILED $logEntry", 'error');
            CakeLog::write('error', "$model FAILED $logEntry");
        }
        return($result);
    }

    public function main() {
        $options = array('conditions' => array('state' => 0, 'next_state' => 1));
        $this->Request->recursive = 0;
        $requests = $this->Request->find('all', $options);

        //See if the apply_changes_on date/time is past
        foreach ($requests AS $request){
            $this->out("Updating request ".$request['Request']['id'], 1, Shell::NORMAL);

            //Update the next_state to "ready"
            $request['Request']['state'] = 1;
            $request['Request']['next_state'] = 2;
            $this->updateRequest($request);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I think you should try: `CakeLog::write('info', $model . $logEntry);`

Comment: Pretty sure my comment above shouldn't make a difference. Both the ways work for me. Do you get the same behavior if you use: `$this->Request->log("$model $logEntry", 'info');` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set up a default listener/scope for those log types?
If not, they will not get logged.

```
// Setup a 'default' cache configuration for use in the application.
Cache::config('default', array('engine' => 'File'));
```

In your bootstrap.php for example

See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-2-migration-guide.html#log

Comment: I see the problem now. I did already have the log setup and it was writing to the log all the time but a different set of logs.  In the Controller/Model it writes to AppName/tmp/logs but in the Shell it writes to AppName/app/tmp/logs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup `default` log stream writing to file, eventually, in `app/Config/bootstrap.php`.

> `CakeLog` **does not auto-configure itself anymore**. As a result log files
>   will not be auto-created anymore if no stream is listening. Make sure
>   you got at least one `default` stream set up, if you want to listen to
>   all types and levels. Usually, you can just set the core `FileLog` class
>   to output into `app/tmp/logs/`:
>
> ```
> CakeLog::config('default', array(
>     'engine' => 'File'
> ));
> ```

See [Logging → Writing to logs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html#writing-to-logs) section of the CookBook 2.x